# Como converter datetime/date para milissegundos em Python?

Tags: python

Como converter um tipo `date` e um `datetime` para milissegundos?

```
>>> ontem # tipo date
datetime.date(2015, 9, 29)
>>> hoje # tipo datetime
datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 30, 18, 15, 36, 856736)
```

Comment: milesegundos desde?

Comment: Desde 1 de Janeiro de 1970.

Answer (score 4):

Construa um `timedelta` a partir da diferença entre sua data e a data de referência, então use [`total_seconds`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) para obter o total de segundos contidos no intervalo. Como esse resultado vem expresso em ponto flutuante, você pode multiplicá-lo por `1000` para obter o resultado em milissegundos (truncando se necessário):

```
>>> UNIX_EPOCH = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
>>> data = datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 30, 18, 15, 36, 856736)
>>> (data - UNIX_EPOCH).total_seconds()*1000
1443636936856.7358
>>> int((data - UNIX_EPOCH).total_seconds()*1000)
1443636936856
```

<sup>[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11111177/520779)</sup>

Se sua data é *timezone-aware*, lembre-se de usar o mesmo fuso horário na data de referência e na data que você quer representar em milissegundos (ou melhor, converter sua data pra UTC antes de fazer essa representação, assim fica tudo canônico). Se tudo estiver em UTC, você também pode obter o valor da "Época Unix" por:

```
UNIX_EPOCH = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
```

(o `utcfromtimestamp` espera um valor em **segundos**, e pode rejeitar valores fora do intervalo 1970-2038, dependendo da implementação; na minha opinião, é mais seguro declarar a constante explicitamente, sem depender desse método)

---

Nota: não faz sentido representar uma data por milissegundos, já que uma data corresponde a um dia inteiro. Sugiro escolher [consistentemente] um instante nessa data (por exemplo meia-noite) e criar um `datetime` a partir do seu `date`.

Comment: No caso o sistema passa apenas a data, antes de retornar o milissegundos é adicionado 0 horas e 0 minutos.

Answer (score 3):

É possível converter de várias maneiras:

### Solução 1

Usando `datetime.timestamp()` presente no Python 3.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> hoje = datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 30)
>>> int(hoje.timestamp() * 1000)
1443582000000
```

> Note que `timestamp()` só funciona com `datetime` e não com `date`

Então é necessário converter para `datetime` se estiver trabalhando com `date`:

```
>>> hoje = datetime.date(2015, 9, 30)
>>> int(datetime.datetime(*hoje.timetuple()[:3]).timestamp() * 1000)
1443582000000
```

### Solução 2

Usando `strftime()`.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> hoje = datetime.date(2015, 9, 30)
>>> int(hoje.strftime('%s')) * 1000
1441681200000
```

> Veja que é `%s` com **s** minúsculo e não com maiúsculo. Se usar **s** maiúsculo retornará apenas os segundos da data (neste caso `00`) e não os segundos totais desde 1970.

Observações:

> Não encontrei referência sobre **s** minúsculo na documentação, mas funciona em Python 3 e 2 no Mac OS.
>
> O `strftime('%s')` retorna apenas os segundos totais arredondados, impedindo precisão em milissegundos.

### Solução 3

Usando `mktime()` do módulo `time`:

```
>>> import datetime, time
>>> hoje = datetime.date(2015, 9, 30)
>>> int(time.mktime(hoje.timetuple()) * 1000)
1443582000000
```

> Note que `mktime` retorna apenas os segundos totais arredondados, não permitindo precisão para os milissegundos.

### Solução 4

Usando `total_seconds()` do `timedelta`:

Ao realizar a diferença entre dois `datetime` é retornado um `timedelta` e a partir dele é possível retornar o número de segundos totais usando `total_seconds()`.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> hoje = datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 30)
>>> (hoje - datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds() * 1000
1443582000000
```

> O `utcfromtimestamp(0)` retorna um `datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0)` como mencionado por mgibsonbr.

Comment: Note que algumas dessas soluções têm precisão limitada em segundos, e outras podem não ser portáveis (ex.: o windows pode não dar suporte a `%s`). P.S. Nas duas primeiras soluções, não seria interessante multiplicar por 1000 *antes* de converter pra `int`, e não depois? (na 3ª não adianta, não sei quanto à 2ª, mas a 1ª tem precisão suficiente pra tal)

Comment: @mgibsonbr realmente o certo é converter para `int` após a multiplicação, eu estava testando `datetime` sem colocar horas e minutos então sempre retornava `.0` no final, acabei me confundindo. Em relação a não funcionar no windows eu já não sei, estou usando Mac OS

Comment: O Mac OS é POSIX, então espera-se que o `%s` funcione mesmo. É no Windows que ele pode ou não estar implementado (e no meu caso - Windows 7, Python 2.7 e 3.4 - não estava).

Answer (score 1):

Tendo em vista que o objeto datetime já possui um método para representar uma data em segundos desde 1º de janeiro de 1970, basta o seguinte:

```
data = datetime.datetime.now()
segundos = data.timestamp()
milissegundos = segundos * 1000
```

Caso você tenha um objeto date, converta-o para datetime:

```
d = datetime.date(2015, 5, 5)    
data = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(d.toordinal())
```

Comment: Lembrando que `timestamp()` só funciona no Python 3